# How to do a reusable plugin in Django, that can be included into a template?

Tags: django, django-templates, django-views, django-apps

How to do a reusable plugin in Django, that can simply be included into a template?

I read several tutorials. They all describe views that return a HttpResponse and extend a base template. That is useful for the main view. But how to set up a simple drop-in view, that just sits in the sidebar of other apps?

I name this requirements:

1. It must not return a HttpResponse, as this is done by the main view.
2. It should be able to display a model.
3. It is easy to include.
4. It should run out-of-the-box without copying and adjusting the plugin's template first.

Questions:

1. How does the interface look like and how is this interface used by the project?
2. How is the technology called?
3. How is this genre of packages called on PyPi?
4. Can you name an example package that shows a canonical implementation?

I guess there are tons of answers, yet it is difficult to find them, as my search keywords are not specific enough. So please excuse to bring up this question, that may sound self-evident to the experienced Django developer.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't want to change anything in the base template or in any other view, then best to use a [Django Middleware](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/http/middleware/). You manipulate the HTML string that is sent to the browser, adding your "sidebar" HTML/CSS/JS to it.

That way, you can activate your sidebar simply by adding your Middleware to the `MIDDLEWARE` list in your project's `settings.py` file.

Comment: That's an interesting approach to inject HTML code. Yet I want to manipulate the base temple, to control where the plugin output goes. I just don't want to manipulate the plugins template by default.

Comment: Ah okay, then I misunderstood. If its okay to manipulate the base template, you could insert the plugin as a [template tag](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/howto/custom-template-tags/) instead.

Comment: Thank you. This should work. The magic is in the load command. The terminology "tag" is just not that intuitive for a plugin to find it easily. Is there a genre name for this kind of plugins on PyPi? Can you name one, that demonstrates the canonical implementation?

Comment: Any app can register template tags. They usually go into a folder `templatetags` within the app's folder. For example [django-allauth](https://django-allauth.readthedocs.io/en/latest/templates.html#account-tags) provides two tags to display user data in templates.

Comment: To be specific, an [inclusion tag](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/howto/custom-template-tags/#inclusion-tags) is what you need here.

Comment: Thank you all. Once I tested this, I will hopefully wrap up the comments into an own answer. It makes stackoverflow less usable, if the best answers are found the comments.